# RAD Custom Filter loses Value Upon filtering another column in the grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, telerik-grid

I have a RadGrid in which I have applied a Custom Filter for one of the columns. Code for custom filter is written in `radGrid_OnItemCommand` method. Custom filter works perfectly,but upon applying a filter to another column,custom filter loses value and filtering is also done only based on the other column filter (non custom filter column).

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Pair grd= e.CommandArgument as Pair;

    if(grd.First.Equals("Custom"))
    {
        e.Canceled = true;
        //All the code to form my custom filter expression

        if(RadGrid1_ItemCommand.MasterTableView.FilterExpression == "")
            RadGrid1_ItemCommand.MasterTableView.FilterExpression = myCustomFilterExpression;

    } else {

        RadGrid1_ItemCommand.MasterTableView.FilterExpression= myCustomFilterExpression+RadGrid1_ItemCommand.MasterTableView.FilterExpression;
        RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Rebind();
        GridColumn col=RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetColumn("colName");
        col.CurrentFilterValue="customFilterValue";

    }
}
```

I have searched other forums and tried different solutions, but could not find a solution. It will be helpful if I can get a suggestion about the problem.
Thanks In Advance